# How to know tag wise score based on answers?

Tags: support, tags

I want to know **tag wise score** I gained excluding  ( edits , question asked by me ) based on answer.

say it for,

**java  , jquery** etc...

Where can I see this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to **tags** tab in your profile to see score for each tag on which you have a post.

> [image]